# Magento: Link to product tabs

Tags: jquery, magento

Most of our products have tabs on their pages (Description, Videos, Downloads, etc)

I'm wanting to be able to create a link on our category page that links to the product page with appropriate tab opened using it's anchor. Something like http://www.example.com/product.html#tab-downloads

Using that type of url will go to the product page and scroll to the tab section but it doesn't have the linked tab opened.

I'm using the Ultimo theme for Magento

I'm sure there's some js that needs to be included on the page, but I'm not exactly sure where to begin. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really Magento related question, but more JS and is about Jumping in page to hash location and opening a tab/click an element.

For the given live example, using jQuery you can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var hash = window.location.hash;
     jQuery(hash).children().click();

    });
</script>
```

You can test this code on your live example, by loading your live example url and running the two lines inside document.ready in the Inspect Element Console.

`children()` is there in this case because you have to `click()` the `anchor` inside the `li` element that has the `#id`. Adjust as required for your actual webpage DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Around line: 324 you will see a < / script > tag. Copy this code inside. And upload it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            if(location.hash == '#tab-downloads') {
                if(jQuery("#product-tabs").hasClass("accor")){jQuery("#product-tabs .tabs-panels").data("tabs").click(jQuery(".tabs-panels .acctab").index(jQuery("#acctab-downloads")))}else{jQuery("#product-tabs .tabs").data("tabs").click(jQuery("#tab-downloads").index())};
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am using the Magento Ultimo theme and was able to get this work for a custom tab (#tab2).

1. I added custom.js to a my sub themes local.xml
2. And this to the custom.js file.

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#rq-product").click(function(){
           jQuery("#tab2").find("a").addClass("current");
           if(jQuery("#product-tabs").hasClass("accor")){
               jQuery("#product-tabs .tabs-panels").data("tabs").click(jQuery(".tabs-panels .acctab").index(jQuery("#acctab2")))
           }
           else {
               jQuery("#product-tabs .tabs").data("tabs").click(jQuery("#tab2").index())
           };
       }); 
   });
   ```
3. And the link I placed in a static block with an *id="rq-product"* and the *href="#tab2"*

Seems to work for me.